# Marketing cloud automation schedule time zone

Tags: sql, salesforce, salesforce-marketing-cloud, journey

Data was received from a third party at 6:30 PM GMT.

- Automation is scheduled at 8:30 PM (GMT) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London
- Business unit time zone : (GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)

Query :

```
SELECT emailaddress,
CAMPAIGN_EXECUTIONDATE
FROM   DataExtension
WHERE DATEDIFF(dd,GETDATE(),CAMPAIGN_EXECUTIONDATE)= 0
```

but it is not getting data from the source DE.

Please suggest what's wrong with the query or something else that I am missing.
Thanks in advance.

I want to run the automation and fetch the data from source data extension and then trigrering the journey via this autimation.

Comment: well, you should ask yourself, what does `DATEDIFF(dd,GETDATE(),CAMPAIGN_EXECUTIONDATE)` return. And if it doesn't return 0, that's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the data fed to DATEDIFF is of same data type. I guess that's the problem

Comment: thanks for the response. yes both have same data type